# JADE: Convert HTML to JADE issues

Tags: html, node.js, pug, webstorm

Im trying to convert the following code from HTML to JADE:

```
<a id="bgndVideo" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Df8ofF1mbdA" class="movie {opacity:1, isBgndMovie:{width:'window',mute:false}, optimizeDisplay:true, showControls:true, ratio:'16/9',startAt:3,quality:'hd720',addRaster:true,lightCrop:true}"></a>
```

HTML2JADE website gives me the following code back:

```
a#bgndVideo.movie.{opacity:1,.isBgndMovie:{width:'window',mute:false},.optimizeDisplay:true,.showControls:true,.ratio:'16/9',startAt:3,quality:'hd720',addRaster:true,lightCrop:true}(href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Df8ofF1mbdA')
```

My issue is that this code doesn't appear to function correctly unlike every other HTML2JADE conversion iv'e done. I noticed that my IDE(WebStorm) is highlight some of the { } in pink, signifying some sort of error. Im just learning jade and I cant figure out the problem, I just know the code doesn't look right... Is there anyone that may be able to help me with this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put it directly in the jade template.

```
<a id="bgndVideo" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Df8ofF1mbdA" class="movie {opacity:1, isBgndMovie:{width:'window',mute:false}, optimizeDisplay:true, showControls:true, ratio:'16/9',startAt:3,quality:'hd720',addRaster:true,lightCrop:true}"></a>
```

It should work.

Comment: Wow awesome! Had no idea you could substitute like that. Does that work in most cases?

Comment: Yup, you can still use plain HTML in Jade templates in some cases.